# Spring @RestControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler prevent exception to be thrown inside of the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, junit

I am using @RestControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotation to handle the exceptions and respond with an appropriate ResponseEntity to the client. I am happy with the way it behaves, except that when I write a negative unit test with expected exception, it fails, since technically the exception was handled by the annotated class and in fact was not thrown. I feel like this is not the correct way of doing things, since in the logs, as well as by the negative test I would like to see that there was an  exception thrown and even though it was handled.

Comment: You could write a unit test which treats your controller as a POJO, and doesn't start the spring framework.

Comment: Shouldn't your stack-level test be _that you get the correct response_ (using MockMvc or TestRestTemplate) instead of how that response was generated?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes I thought about that, but still it felt to me that it would make more sense to do it in my described way. Thank you.